# How to close epiphany through a script with cron?

Tags: cron, browser, xdotool, xte

I have been making scripts to open and close a specific website with a cronjob on the raspberry Pi. The opening script works perfectly. It is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0 && epiphany-browser http://mywebsite
sleep 30
xte "key F11" -x:0
xte "key F5" -x:0
```

But the one to close the browser doesn't work at all, and I can't figure out why. Is there something wrong with the script? I made it by looking at this [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/583246/can-i-close-firefox-browser-tab-or-firefox-browser-from-ubuntu-terminal).

```
#!/bin/bash 

WID = `xdotool search "epiphany-browser" | head-1`
xdotool windowactivate --sync $WID
xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+q
```

Note: Couldn't get this code to work but the "killall" command works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kill it!

```
#!/bin/bash
killall epiphany
```

And btw: on my system (Debian Jessie) the process name is just `epiphany`.
You can see the process list e.g. with `ps -A`.

Comment: Sorry, i tried that before but it didn't work

Comment: Changed the binary name.

Comment: Still doesn't work :S I thought it could be from being in fullscreen mode so i removed the line related to the key F11 but nothing. Maybe it is an epiphany issue from closing with terminal?

Comment: I just tried it and it works here. Try `killall -s 9 epiphany`. And start Epiphany for a test manually from a console and see what it drops to stdout/stderr.

Comment: sorry nothing, i checked the process of epiphany and it says "epiphany-browse" but it still doesn't work. Could you be a bit more specific with the stdout/stderr?

Comment: Start it in a terminal and see what it messages it prints there while you try to kill it. Try to start `epiphany` and `epiphany-browser`.

Comment: sorry about the long wait, was having lunch. When i type epiphany and try to kill it it shows" no process was found" but it works with epiphany-browser, although it won't work in the script.

Comment: Updated the answer with all the errors it shows from starting the process "epiphany-browser" and i can't type anything after because the process doesn't finish, it stucks on the last line i posted above.

Comment: To start clear: What is the output of `ps -A|grep epiphany` when the browser is running?

Comment: Do you mind moving the discussion on to chat? It might become too long and confusing here with some posts. I've done what you suggested and this comes up `14661 ? 00:00:17 epiphany-browse`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26393/discussion-between-angelfmf-and-jodka-lemon).

Comment: Found the problem. Should have known that the issue was the script and not the commands. It was missing the permissions to run. A simple "chmod" solved it. Thanks for the help anyway.